# Strange retain cycle when using external NSThread

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, swift, macos

I've written a Grand Central Dispatch like class that queues blocks to be executed on a pool of threads. (Why you wonder? Because I need a GCD with thread affinity).

The code is quite simple:

```
static let sharedInstance=CuprumOperationQueue()

func addOperation(operation: ()->()) {
    dispatch_async(_operationsQueue) {
        //Place the operation on the queue
        self._operations.append(operation)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0)) {
            self.pushQueue()
        }
    }
}

func getOperation() -> ClosureType? {
    var operation: ClosureType?=nil;

    dispatch_sync(_operationsQueue) {
        if (!self._operations.isEmpty) {
            operation=self._operations.removeFirst();
        }
    }

    return operation;
}

func pushQueue() {
    for thread in _threads {
        if (CFRunLoopIsWaiting(thread.runLoop)) {
            if let operation = self.getOperation() {
                CFRunLoopPerformBlock(thread.runLoop, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, operation); //(2)
                CFRunLoopWakeUp(thread.runLoop);
            } else {
                //There are no more operations to perform
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use a GCD serial queue (_operationsQueue) to serialize access to the array with blocks (_operations). The threads (running a CFRunLoop with an observer) call pushQueue when the run loop is about to sleep.

I use the queue as follows:

```
[[CuprumOperationQueue sharedInstance] addOperation:^{ //(1)
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^(void) {
            NSLog(@"test %p",self);
        }];
}];
```

The problem is that the object calling the above snippet is never released. It's not reported as a leak in Instruments, so there is at least some reachable reference to it. I just don't see where. I suspect a retain cycle somewhere, because removing the self reference from the NSLog statement does cause the object to be released. But this can't be the whole problem, as replacing the line with (1) for the equivalent using a NSOperationQueue also causes the object to be properly released (even with self reference in the second block). So it's only in combination with my custom queue that there is a problem.

If, in the Swift-based queue class, I remove the call on the line with (2), the object is also properly released.

As you can see there isn't much code left to be causing problems, but I really don't see where this might cause a retain cycle.

Any insights will be highly appreciated.